# Which countries force all arriving international passengers to claim their luggage for the purpose of customs inspection?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, airports, international-travel

I read on [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/150507/1810) by [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog):

> Your layover is in a country where all arriving international passengers must claim their luggage for the purpose of customs inspection. In this case, the bag is tagged for your final destination, but you must pick it up, clear customs, and re-check it at the layover airport.

Which countries force all arriving international passengers to claim their luggage for the purpose of customs inspection, even if passengers have one more leg in their trip?

Comment: Are you differentiating between a connecting international flight and a domestic one?

Comment: Other than the USA and Canada?

Comment: Clearing Customs on first arrival into the country is default worldwide, the list of countries that *don't* require you to do this is probably much shorter.  If you meant countries where you need to claim bags *even in international transit*, please clarify the question.

Comment: @lambshaanxy and Doc thanks for the clarification question, I meant "claim their luggage for the purpose of customs inspection, even if passengers have one more leg in their trip": I indeed didn't specify whether the leg is international, I'm curious to know about both the domestic and the international cases

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes sometimes I go to countries other than Canada and US

Comment: In the EU it is the default that you clear customs at the final airport. So if for example you fly EWR-FRA-MUC you will pass immigration in FRA, but pick up your luggage and pass customs (where you will probably just take the green lane) in MUC